# lightning:textarea - focus method not visible

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a lightning:textarea in which I append text by clicking on items in a menuButton.

I would also like to focus on the textarea but the focus method doesn't seem to be visible.

with:
`component.get('myTextarea').focus();`
I get:
`Access Check Failed! Component.method():'markup://lightning:focus' is not visible.`

Is this a bug? Has anyone come across this? 
Any workarounds?

I haven't had any luck with the dom element either: `component.get('myTextarea').getElement().focus()`

*For reference: I can successfully call the second available method in this component (showHelpMessageIfInvalid) ref: [lightning:textarea](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_textarea.htm)*

Clarification: LockerService is enabled.

Comment: Just to confirm, do you have Lightning Lockerservice enabled in your org?

Comment: Yes, LockerService is enabled